# how to assert search.query?

Tags: query, search

I have these lines in my test class:

```
Contact con = new Contact();
    con.FirstName = 'test';
    con.LastName = 'test';
    insert con;
List<List<SObject>> toSearch = Search.query('find \'test\' IN ALL FIELDS returning Contact (Name)') ;
system.assertEquals(true, toSearch.size() > 0)
```

the assertion results an error because the list is empty. this is what i want to know, why did it turned out to be empty when I have already inserted  a contact record for the search.query to execute?

Comment: you have to use Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults) in test class else sosl return always empty list check this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm

Comment: @RatanPaul you can post this as an answer

Comment: thank you @RatanPaul , I added the Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults) as given from your link but it seems to be still empty. should the Id fixedSearchResults be equal to contact Id?

Comment: ofcourse @SantanuBoral. Yes Mae you have to set your contact Id in Test.setFixedSearchResults

Comment: As an aside, you should probably avoid using search.query unless it really is a dynamic query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults)` in test class else sosl return always empty list

check this documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm

### **From documentation.**

> Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests To ensure that test methods always
>   behave in a predictable way, any Salesforce Object Search Language
>   (SOSL) query that is added to an Apex test method returns an empty set
>   of search results when the test method executes. If you do not want
>   the query to return an empty list of results, you can use the
>   Test.setFixedSearchResults system method to define a list of record
>   IDs that are returned by the search. All SOSL queries that take place
>   later in the test method return the list of record IDs that were
>   specified by the Test.setFixedSearchResults method. Additionally, the
>   test method can call Test.setFixedSearchResults multiple times to
>   define different result sets for different SOSL queries. If you do not
>   call the Test.setFixedSearchResults method in a test method, or if you
>   call this method without specifying a list of record IDs, any SOSL
>   queries that take place later in the test method return an empty list
>   of results.
>
> The list of record IDs specified by the Test.setFixedSearchResults
>   method replaces the results that would normally be returned by the
>   SOSL query if it were not subject to any WHERE or LIMIT clauses. If
>   these clauses exist in the SOSL query, they are applied to the list of
>   fixed search results. For example:
>
> ```
> @isTest
> private class SoslFixedResultsTest1 {
>
>     public static testMethod void testSoslFixedResults() {
>        Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
>        fixedSearchResults[0] = '001x0000003G89h';
>        Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
>        List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
>                                          IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
>                                             Account(id, name WHERE name = 'test' LIMIT 1)];
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> > SOSL queries for ContentDocument (File) or ContentNote (Note) entities
> >     require using setFixedSearchResults with ContentVersion IDs to remain
> >     consistent with how Salesforce indexes and searches for files and
> >     notes.
>
> Although the account record with an ID of 001x0000003G89h may not
>   match the query string in the FIND clause ('test'), the record is
>   passed into the RETURNING clause of the SOSL statement. If the record
>   with ID 001x0000003G89h matches the WHERE clause filter, the record is
>   returned. If it does not match the WHERE clause, no record is
>   returned.